# R lapply different function to each element of list

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have a list (in R) where the elements are different data types, e.g., the first element is numeric and the second element is character.  I would like to apply a different function to each element.  For example, in the code below I try to apply the sum function only to the first element and the length function only to the second element.  Is there a way to apply a different function to each element of a list (without breaking up the list)?

```
data <- list(
  A = rnorm(10),
  B = letters[1:10]
)

lapply(data, list(sum, length))

mapply(function(x) sum, length, data)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about

```
mapply(function(a,b) b(a), data, list(sum, length))
```

Notice that we put the functions in `mapply` in a list as well.

Comment: You could do something similar with `do.call`, but you have to adjust `data` slightly to be a list of lists.

Comment: ...interestingly, it seems that (ignoring the need to recycle either argument) simply writing a `for` loop that applies each function in turn is ~5x times faster.

Comment: Well written for loops are usually faster in my experience, although the speed up usually isn't that large.

Comment: @joran I tried all the methods (mapply, sapply, vapply and a loop) and get the same time with example data like `n  <- 1e6;
nc <- 1e3;
data <- list(
  rnorm(n),
  sample(letters,n,TRUE)
)[sample(1:2,nc,TRUE)]` This is a weird example to consider, though. There's no reason to compute `length` if all the vectors have the same length (as seems to be the case for the OP).

Answer (score 6):

I would do something like

```
sapply( data, function(x) (if(is.character(x)) length else sum)(x) )
```

---

*Complicated alternatives*. If speed is a concern, `vapply` should be faster:

```
vapply( data, function(x) (if(is.character(x)) length else sum)(x), numeric(1) )
```

If you need to use `length` many times, it's fast to use `lengths` (available in R 3.2.0+):

```
res          <- lengths(data)
get_sum      <- !sapply(data,is.character)
res[get_sum] <- sapply(data[get_sum],sum)
```